# How to add link to Gatsby config file

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to insert a link for shortcut icon in the gatsby-config.js file but it seems to not work. Obviously I'm also using graphql.

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'xxxx',
    description: 'xxxx',
    keywords:
      'test test test',
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'shortcut icon',
        url:
          'https://xxxx.png',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-react-helmet'],
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-html-attributes',
      options: {
        lang: 'en',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add this via `gatsby-plugin-manifest` [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-manifest/#automatic-mode-configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/#configuration-options) are the options you can add in the `gatsby-cnfig`. From the docs:

> Options available to set within gatsby-config.js include:
>
> 1. siteMetadata (object)
> 2. plugins (array)
> 3. pathPrefix (string)
> 4. polyfill (boolean)
> 5. mapping (object)
> 6. proxy (object)
> 7. developMiddleware (function)

A "link to a shortcut" is not part of these options.

TLDR: You can't.